# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages - laravel / valet

Tags: laravel, terminal, valet

I am running this command on the terminal:

```
composer global require laravel/valet
```

but I got this error message:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer is locked to version v2.16.4 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer v2.16.4 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.5) does not satisfy that requirement.

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require laravel/valet:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require laravel/valet:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

I search on google but couldn't find any solution.

**PHP version I am running is 8.08 on MAMP**

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Run `composer global require laravel/valet:*`.
This will check any installable version is available for your dev environment and install the package.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I will check it.

Comment: After following this: https://www.twilio.com/blog/how-to-create-local-wordpress-setup-using-laravel-valet-in-5-minutes I can run the valet but when I run this command `mysql -u root` I am getting `zsh: command not found: mysql`

Comment: can you tell me why?

Comment: Run `alias mysql=/usr/local/mysql/bin` before running `mysql -u root`. If it works, then the answer is, mysql is not available in you `$PATH`.

Comment: Now, I am getting `zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql`

Comment: can you check the path of your mysql bin?

Comment: Run `echo $PATH` to check if the mysql path is there or not. If not try to add the path to `$PATH`. I think this answer will help you: https://superuser.com/a/330349.

Comment: Do you mean to run this command `sudo nano /etc/paths`

Comment: not at all. see my new comment. It will help.

Comment: Here is the result after run the echo `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:~/.composer/vendor/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin/`

Comment: now, I can see mysql  is added in the path: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:~/.composer/vendor/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin/`

Comment: still getting the same mesage :(

Comment: Now, It seems working after adding this: `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin`

Comment: Okay great! Enjoy.